# How do I stop this from infinitely repeating, but still keep the loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

On line 33, there is a break to stop the code from repeating indefinitely, but I would like it to take part in the `while loop`.

**The Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
while (true){
    {
        cout << "This program counts by twos to any number that is inputted by the user." << endl;
        cout << "Input an even number to start counting." << endl;
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        if (!cin.fail())//fails if input is not an integer
        {
            if (input < 0)//makes sure all numbers are positive
            {
                cout << "That is not a positive number. Try again?" << endl;
            }
            else if (input % 2 != 0) // makes sure all numbers are even
            {
                cout << "That is not an even number. Try again?" << endl;
            }
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i <= input; i += 2) //uses a for loop to actually do the counting once you know that the number is even.
                {
                    cout << i << endl;

                }
            }

        }
        if (cin.fail())//returns this when you input anything other than an integer. 
        {
            cout << "That is not a digit, try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

If you guys could help me find why this repeats, that would really help.

Comment: `but I would like it to take part in the while loop` What do you mean? What is the desired functionality of this code?

Comment: The `break` _will_ break you out of your (`while`) loop. Is this not what you want? Incidentally, your `if (cin.fail())` at the end looks like it should be simplified to `else`.

Comment: Rather than using an endless `while (true)` here, you should probably move `int input;` outside the loop, and turn the loop into `do { .... } while (!cin.fail());` -- eliminating the need for a `break` at all, and making the intentions more clear.

Comment: `help me find why this repeats` It has an infinite while loop, you have a `break` condition when you enter something that is not a number, as far as i can tell this works: http://ideone.com/vkSLsh

Comment: Should there be an additional `break` after the `for` loop ?
And I would recommend, not to check `cin.fail()` twice, but use `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `break` statement after the for loop in order to exit the loop.  Without the `break` the for loop will execute and print your output and then control will fall to the end of the while loop where it will start back at the top of the loop.

I would also suggest changing `if (cin.fail())` to just `else` as you are already checking `if (!cin.fail())`.  You also need to ignore the rest of the input and clear the error flags if you want to loop again.

You also had a extra set of brackets in the while loop.  With those changes your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "This program counts by twos to any number that is inputted by the user." << endl;
        cout << "Input an even number to start counting." << endl;
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        if (!cin.fail())//fails if input is not an integer
        {
            if (input < 0)//makes sure all numbers are positive
            {
                cout << "That is not a positive number. Try again?" << endl;
            }
            else if (input % 2 != 0) // makes sure all numbers are even
            {
                cout << "That is not an even number. Try again?" << endl;
            }
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i <= input; i += 2) //uses a for loop to actually do the counting once you know that the number is even.
                {
                    cout << i << endl;

                }
                break;  // exit the while loop
            }

        }
        else //else when you input anything other than an integer. 
        {
            cout << "That is not a digit, try again." << endl;
            cin.clear();  // reset the error flags
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // clear any extra input
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have to call `cin.clear()` before calling `cin.ignore()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you print, I'm guessing your problem is that you want to give the user a chance to try again to enter a number, but after one failure, it continuously fails no matter what you enter. If that's the case, replace your `break` with `cin.clear()`. That will tell the stream that you've recovered from the error and are ready to receive more input.

If you're going to do that, though, your program now has no exit condition, so you'll want to add a `break` (or `return 0`) just after the for-loop.